# angularjs, unable to assign values to multiple attributes in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular2-directives

I am stuck with a problem where I have written a custom directive to rate with stars, where the user can rate from 1 to 5 by clicking on the stars, I was successful in achieving this.

```
<span starrating class="star-rating" rating="ratedValue" ></span>
```

But I am using the same directive to display the customer reviews, where I have a isolated scope variable called "rating", and this works well too.

```
<span starrating class="star-rating" readOnlyFlag="true" rating="reviewItem.rating" ></span>
```

But this time I dont want the user to click and change the rating. Hence I am declaring another variable in the isolated scope of the directive called "readOnlyFlag". But when I assign the value for readOnlyFlag in the directive as an attribute. I am unable get the value in the link function.

The directive code is below :

```
angular.module("pageDirectives",[]).directive("starrating", function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        template :'<ul class="list-inline">'
    + ' <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="{filled: $index<=selectedIndex, filled:$index<rating}" ng-click="toggleIndex($index)">'
        + '  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star fa-2x"></i>'
        + ' </li>'
        + '</ul>',
        scope : {
            rating : '=',
            readOnlyFlag : '=',

    },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.stars=[1,2,3,4,5];
            scope.toggleIndex= function(index){
                if(!scope.readonlyFlag){
                    scope.selectedIndex=index;
                    scope.rating=index+1;
                }

            }
        }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `read-only-flag="true"` to get the value into your directive. Please notice the dashes in the attribute.

Isolated scope camelCase are dashed in attributes.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nqqyce1k/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
 $scope.readOnly = false;
 $scope.reviewItem = {
     rating: 3
    };
})
.directive("starrating", function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        template :'<ul class="list-inline">'
    + ' <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="{filled: $index<=selectedIndex, filled:$index<rating}" ng-click="toggleIndex($index)">'
        + '  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star fa-2x"></i>'
        + ' </li>'
        + '</ul>',
        scope : {
            rating : '=',
            readOnlyFlag : '=',

    },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.stars=[1,2,3,4,5];
            scope.toggleIndex= function(index){
             console.log(scope.readOnlyFlag)
                if(!scope.readOnlyFlag){
                    scope.selectedIndex=index;
                    scope.rating=index+1;
                }

            }
        }
};
});
```

```css
.filled  {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    toggle read-only <input ng-model="readOnly" type="checkbox"/>
    <span starrating class="star-rating" read-only-flag="readOnly" rating="rating" ></span>
    <h2>
    always read-only
    </h2>
 <span starrating class="star-rating" read-only-flag="true" rating="reviewItem.rating" ></span>
</div>
```